# Getting "undefined method `include?'" for request.user_agent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, user-agent

I've got this line of code:

```
if request.user_agent.include?("iPhone") then
```

But I'm occasionally getting this error:

```
"undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass"
```

When checking logs on the error, there isn't a "`HTTP_USER_AGENT`" for the user that is getting the error.

So how can I fix that line so it doesn't throw an error if there isn't an `HTTP_USER_AGENT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 2.3.xx you can also use Object#try

`request.user_agent.try(:include?, 'iphone')`

Check [here](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/823b623fe2de8846c37aa13250010809ac940b57) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check it for nil or rescue the exception yourself.

Answer (score 0):

NSD is right.

You could also use `try` as a short cut:

```
request.user_agent.try(:include?, "iPhone")
```

`try` will not error when its receiver is nil, so you can chain them together, like this:

```
foo.try(:bar).try(:baz)
```